# when app is in background and if internet connection lost, app is getting crashed

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

We are working on react native and we implemented NetInfo event listener to check internet connectivity.

We are also calling fetch() on events to get data from google api. When app is in background and if internet connection lost then app is getting crashed with following error:

```
ReactNativeJS: Network request failed
E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example, PID: 30344
E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Network request failed, stack:
E AndroidRuntime: onerror@25623:21
E AndroidRuntime: dispatchEvent@10670:19
E AndroidRuntime: setReadyState@27824:19
E AndroidRuntime: __didCompleteResponse@27660:19
E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@27764:57
E AndroidRuntime: emit@9771:28
E AndroidRuntime: __callFunction@7571:39
E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@7443:21
E AndroidRuntime: guard@7381:3
E AndroidRuntime: callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@7442:6
E AndroidRuntime:
E AndroidRuntime: at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:97)
E AndroidRuntime: at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:81)
E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:318)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I ReactNativeJS: auth/network-request-failed
I ReactNativeJS: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example/.MainActivity
```

I have created android react native module to get GPS current location using NETWORK_PROVIDER.

```
public class GpsLocationCheckModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LocationListener{
private Promise promiseCallback;
public boolean gps_enabled = false;
private ReactApplicationContext mReactContext;
private Activity currentActivity;
private static final String SETTINGS_FAILURE = "SETTINGS_FAILURE";
private LocationManager locationManager;
public static final String TAG = GpsLocationCheckModule.class.getSimpleName();
private String messageText;
private Location location;
private boolean isPopUpDisplayed = false;

public GpsLocationCheckModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    //reactContext.addActivityEventListener(mActivityEventListener);
    mReactContext = reactContext;
   reactContext.addActivityEventListener(mActivityEventListener);        
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "GpsServiceLocation"; //this will be use at JS side.
}

@ReactMethod
public void checkLocation(String message, Promise promise) { 
    currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
    promiseCallback=promise;
    messageText= message;
    Log.i(TAG,"check location");
    locationManager = (LocationManager)mReactContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0, 0, this);        
    boolean gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(!gps_enabled){
        if(!isPopUpDisplayed){
            isPopUpDisplayed = true;
            Log.i(TAG,"checklocatoin disabled" + Boolean.toString(isPopUpDisplayed));
            displayPromptForEnablingGPS(currentActivity,messageText,promiseCallback);
        }            
    }       
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i(TAG,"location changed");
    String msg = "New Latitude: " + location.getLatitude()
            + "New Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
    Log.i(TAG,msg);
    WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
    params.putDouble("Longitude", location.getLongitude());
    params.putDouble("Latitude", location.getLatitude());
    //locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
     Log.i(TAG,"removed");
   sendEvent(mReactContext, "locationChanged", params);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.i(TAG,"disabled");
    Log.i(TAG,"ispopup disabled" + Boolean.toString(isPopUpDisplayed));
    if(!isPopUpDisplayed){
        isPopUpDisplayed = true;
        Log.i(TAG,"ispopup inside disabled" + Boolean.toString(isPopUpDisplayed));
        displayPromptForEnablingGPS(currentActivity,messageText,promiseCallback);
    } 
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.i(TAG,"enabled");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.i(TAG,"status changed");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void displayPromptForEnablingGPS(final Activity activity, final String message, final Promise promise) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    final String action = android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;

    builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(message))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                            activity.startActivityForResult(new Intent(action), 1);                                        
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) { 
                            popupRejected();                               
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    builder.create().show();
}

private final ActivityEventListener mActivityEventListener = new BaseActivityEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        currentActivity = activity;
        checkLocationService(true); 
    }
};

public void checkLocationService(Boolean status){
    WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
    map.putString("status", "success");  
    isPopUpDisplayed=false;
    Log.i(TAG,"ispopup checklocation" + Boolean.toString(isPopUpDisplayed));
    if(promiseCallback != null){
        promiseCallback.resolve(map);
        promiseCallback = null;
    }            
}
public void popupRejected(){
    isPopUpDisplayed = false;
    Log.i(TAG,"ispopup rejected" + Boolean.toString(isPopUpDisplayed));
    if(promiseCallback != null){                               
        promiseCallback.reject(SETTINGS_FAILURE,"Gps enabling failed");
    }
}

 /*
 * Internal function for communicating with JS
 */
private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, 
    String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
    if (reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
        reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, params);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for CatalystInstance...");
    }
}   
}
```

I am calling this module in componentDidMount() in following way:

```
componentDidMount() {
     NetInfo.addEventListener(
        'change',
        this._handleConnectionInfoChange
    );   
    NetInfo.fetch().done(
       (connectionInfo) => { this.setState({connectionInfo}); }
    );  
    GpsServiceLocation.checkLocation(this.state.message).catch((error)=>{});
    }
```

Event listener for location updates

```
constructor(props) {
      if (!this.evEmitter) {
      // Register Listener Callback - has to be removed later
       this.evEmitter = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('locationChanged', this.onLocationChange.bind(this));      
    }  
   }
```

Listener function

```
onLocationChange (e: Event) { 
         NetInfo.fetch().done(
       (connectionInfo) => { 

  if(connectionInfo != 'NONE'){     
    if(e.Latitude != 0 && e.Longitude != 0){ 
             fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='+e.Latitude+','+e.Longitude+'&destinations='+destLatlng+'&mode=walking&key=<key>')
                .then((responseData) => responseData.json())
                .done((responseData)=>{
                     ...
                });
         }
      }
   }
   }
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using try-catch statements to trap the errors and move on?

Comment: Hi Enfyve, yes I wrapped that code in try-catch statements but it's not handling when app is in background app. I also tried using AppState to check if app is in background then I was returning back in OnLocationChange function so that fetch() doesn't execute but it was still crashing.

Comment: Rather than doing the fetch then checking if connection info != 'NONE,' why not do `NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(...`

Comment: In Listener function? Let me try that..

Comment: It didn't work Enfyve. I am sure it's happening due to fetch() or firebase call but try-catch statements is not able to catch that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of issue. It was happening due to fetch(). If you are using fetch() and internet connection lost while app in background then fetch() method fails due to Network error.

I added catch() in fetch() to handle network related errors. Below is syntax.

```
     fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='+e.Latitude+','+e.Longitude+'&destinations='+destLatlng+'&mode=walking&key=<key>')
            .then((responseData) => responseData.json())
            .done((responseData)=>{
                 ...
     }).catch((error)=>{
         //handle your error here
     });
```